# plot totally fragmented, WorkingPrecision,matlab comparison

Tags: plotting, precision-and-accuracy, matlab

I am trying to plot

```
F2q0overLambdaSimpler3[m_] := 
1/(Sqrt[2] (4*Pi)^2)*1/(2 (m^4) )*(1/Sqrt[1 - 4 m^2]*(2 - 10 m^2 + 8 m^4)*
 ArcTanh[Sqrt[1 - 4 m^2]/(1 - 2 m^2)] + 
2*(2 m^2 - 3 m^4 + (2 - 6 m^2) Log[m]))$
```

Just using

```
Plot[F2q0overLambdaSimpler3[m], {m, 1/(200*10^3), 1/(100*10^3)}]
```

But the result looks like this:

[image]

Then I plotted this function using matlab:

[image]

How do I get mathematica plotting it equally nice? I already tried things like

```
WorkingPrecision -> 100
```

or even 1000 what yields a very weird behaviour....  Any suggestions?

Comment: can you post the Matlab code?

Comment: fyi, your function has many Indeterminate values. It can't be correct. Try `data = Table[{i, F2q0overLambdaSimpler3[i]}, {i, 1/(200*10^3), 1/(100*10^3), .00000001}] // N` and you'll see. You Matlab code must be different that the Mathematica code shown.

Comment: poss related http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/47984/plot3d-not-showing-plot/47993#47993

Answer (score 3):

The reason for the fragmented plot is that the function evaluates to `Indeterminate` for most of the input values in the plot range, when using machine precision arithmetic. (Specifically, the argument to `ArcTanh` is equal to `1.0` with machine precision, and `ArcTanh[1.0]` is `Indeterminate`).

Even if we didn't have this problem with `ArcTanh`, there is another reason not to use machine precision, which is that the function contains three terms which almost exactly cancel. For example:

```
Operate[HoldForm, Expand @ F2q0overLambdaSimpler3[5*^-6]] ~N~ 40

(*
Plus[3.582244801432892462853067372970466380829 * 10^8, 
 1.749005611145337947993200403185346578823 * 10^20, 
-1.749005611148920192794633295648251690568 * 10^20]
*)

ReleaseHold[%]
(* -5.2044372*10^-12 *)
```

Therefore it will be essential to increase the `WorkingPrecision` in `Plot`. For example:

```
Plot[F2q0overLambdaSimpler3[m], {m, 5*^-6, 1*^-5}, WorkingPrecision -> 50]
```

[image]

Clearly this is a very different plot to that obtained with Matlab. As a check on the *Mathematica* result, we can look at the series expansion of the function.

```
Series[F2q0overLambdaSimpler3[m], {m, 0, 7}]
```

I won't copy the full result here, but the first term is $\frac{m^2 (12 \log (m)+7)}{48 \sqrt{2} \pi ^2}$:

Evaluating this at the start of the plot range:

```
((7 + 12 Log[m]) m^2)/(48 Sqrt[2] π^2) /. m -> 5.0*^-6

(* -5.20444*10^-12 *)
```

This result agrees with what we see in the plot. Of course this doesn't **prove** anything but perhaps the next step should be to examine the Matlab result more closely. What precision did Matlab use to compute the plot?